# Persist dynamic map in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

```
is there any way to persist the map with dymamic fields.Here is sample code
Table :
A table with more than 200 fields.

POJO :
<code> 
<pre>
public class DynamicEntity {
private Long id;
 private Map<String,String> fields = new HashMap();
 public Long getId() {
 return id;
 }
 public void setId(Long id) {
 this.id = id;
 }
 public void add(String key,String value){
 fields.put(key,value);
 }
}
</pre>
```

The map in the pojo holding dynamic fields.
Transactional code ..
    
    
    `GenericData data = new GenericData();
    data.addField("name", "CF");
    data.addField("description", "CF-USA");
    data.addField("server", "ServerName");
    //get the session
    session.save(data);`

is there any way to save the map here when I save the pojo ?Here fields are not configured in  hbm file because all the fields are dynamic.

My basic idea is not to configure 200 fields in hbm file.

```
Regards,
Ravi.
```

Answer (score 0):

hibernate can't persist without the mapping. You either specify them by hand or generate them on the fly based on the content of the map. To map the columns to the map you can use the dynamic-component mapping.